# Installing alfresco 3.4 on jboss with mysql

Tags: mysql, jboss, alfresco

I am trying to install alfresco 3.4 into an already existent jboss instance but the documentation I have followed appears to be incorrect. First issue is the docs mention an extensions folder that does not exist in any of the Alfresco downloads that I have found. Second issue is in the documentation on how to configure the database for alfresco. It tells me to run a script that is located inside "extra/databases/mysql", again in this case the extra dir does not exist in my dist of alfresco. I have been google-ing but many of the other howtos I see are even more impossible to follow.

[link to docs I have been trying to follow](http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc/tasks/alfv3-jboss-install.html)

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you trying to install, Community or Enterprise? That doc is for enterprise which is slightly different to community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: If you have an Enterprise version, then you can just download the *.EAR file from the network Downloads. Run the following lines in a MySql window:

```
create database alfresco default character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
grant all on alfresco.* to 'alfresco'@'localhost' identified by 'alfresco' with grant option;
grant all on alfresco.* to 'alfresco'@'localhost.localdomain' identified by 'alfresco' with grant option;
```

(it's the same as that should be in the extras/databases.. location)

It should contain an extension folder. And you don't need an extension folder to start Alfresco.........

Second: You have community edition.......

Just look at this wiki page: [WIKI](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Deploying_Alfresco_on_JBoss)

Don't forget to put the mysql jdbc jar in the server default lib folder.

Comment: Can I download the enterprise version of alfresco for free or does that cost money?

Comment: You can download the enterprise version with a 30 day Trial I guess. http://www.alfresco.com/products/ecm/enttrial/?product_module=DM , The community version is completely free.